# How to configure nginx to redirect traffic if cookie is set, then decide on percentage probability the destination

Tags: nginx, proxy, ab-testing

I need some help for a use case that I want to implement in nginx proxy that I could not find a direct solution in nginx manual.

Use case:
I have one old website that I replatformed in new technology.
I want to redirect(serve via new site) all users that don't are not using the old website (I can tell this if they are missing a cookie ex `old_web_cookie`)

Then for all users in the category above (new users that never visited the site at all, or opened private browsers), want to split them by 80% of them still visit the old web, and 20% of them receive responses of new web.

**Architecture**
Current architecture for test purpose is super simple, one nginx proxy and 2 docker containers. One containing `web` and a new one `newweb`

part of my nginx.conf

```
server {
    server_name test.dev;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log json_combined;

    client_max_body_size 20M;

    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    http2_push_preload on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.dev/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.dev/privkey.pem;

    location / {
      // HERE I want to implement the code that I am asking about
      if ($http_cookie ~* "old_web_cookie") {
         // so all users that are using the old web (web) i want still to be served from it
         proxy_pass http://web:8080;
      } else {
         // split traffic 80% go to web (old web)
         proxy_pass http://web:8080;
         // 20% of traffic here go to http://newweb:9080
         proxy_pass http://newweb:9080;
      }

      // rest is not interesting for the question
      proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $remote_addr;
    }
  }
```

In my nginx.conf file above, I put pseudocode explaining the logic I want to implement but that of course doesn't work.
First I noticed that nginx does not have `else` statement, and secondly don't know how to do something like 20% of users use this location (proxy) 80% this other one